# Missing file when using git

Tags: git

Currently, I have a git repository with project files on bitbucket, and I would like to set the background of one of my classes to an image in the repository.

However, when I try to set the image of the class (I am using Greenfoot, and this is possible through right clicking a class in the class tree) to a custom file, it returns a "File Not Found Exception" and removes the image.

I would like to add images, although stack overflow does not allow me to as I am a new user without any reputation.

I'm also quite new to git too, so any tips on git would be appreciated.

Thanks,
SepLite

Comment: Presumably you are trying to use a physical form of the image rather than the tracked source code in your Git repository right?

Comment: Load the image to web-hosting and paste it here if needed. (dropbox, sugarsync, copy etc)

Comment: scrowler: I think so? I am trying to use a .jpg file in my git repository. However, for the time being, everything works, as the file still exists on the remote server and the class still 'points' to the file. The only thing now is the minor inconvenience every time I add the file. Thanks anyways!